# How I can increase the connection time of a Bluetooth LE Connection?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

When I am connected with the CBCentralManager to an CBPeripheral, then its possible to read and write data during CBCharacteristics.

But after about 30 seconds the delegate method didDisconnectPeripheral will call.

In my Use Case it could happen, that I need more connection time about 1 - 2 Minutes.

Is it possible to increase the connection time?

Comment: Why does the peripheral disconnects?

Comment: I don't know it seems after 30 seconds automatically

Comment: Is it because you have to make a pairing? What does says the doc of your device?

Comment: There is no pairing.. its just a write and a notify characteristic and the device is another iOS device working with the CBPeripheralManager